# How to prevent users changing variables via firebug in ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, variables, firebug

I allow my users to favorite an update or a forum topic.
So when a user tries to favorite one of these i will send via Ajax 2 things, the item_id(update or topic) as id(ex. 1321313213) and its type("update" or "topic") as string.

However lets say someones tries to favorite an update with the id untouched but the type is changed to "topic"(via firebug or whatever else)...

This should not procceed since this combination is not correct... how can i assure that the item_id being sent is an update or a topic since this ID might co-exist in both tables???

**Current solution:**

Create a hidden input element and add as value 5 random characters (a-zA-Z0-9) and md5 type name(update or topic)

like:

```
$random_str = $this->my_model->generateRandomString(5);
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $random_str.md5("update"); ?>" id="type" />
```

so when i try to validate the data to check if it is an update or topic i split the type on the first 5 characters and later and check if the later characters are md5 hashed are update or topic and continue validation

I would like some help in case this can be altered as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server side script (PHP) must always assume it's getting bogus data. Never rely solely on javascript to handle any sanitization / verification.

If your javascript can determine if the job should be "update" or "topic", I'm sure your PHP can do that as well. Probably using a few more DB queries or some such, but that's the price you've got to pay.

Comment: of course i never reply to javascript data thats why i always validate them as well via php... but this time i cant find a way to validate that the ID being sent is an update or topic since this ID cant co-exist in both tables in the future... and i cant also send anything else that can help validation since this can be altered as well...

Comment: In that case I suggest you add an identifier to tell PHP "this is an update". If that identifier is not there, abort.

Comment: can you be a little more specific?What i could also do is instead of doing 1 ajax call in 1 function... i could create 2 separate functions and 1 call on update function and the other on topic function which can also solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking at the problem from the wrong perspective. Especially from You server side (PHP) code.

Your server gets data. It gets data which is something like that: `user` (from session), `id` and `type`. Your server needs to ask a question: is it valid data? If it is -- save it to DB; If it is not -- do not save it to DB. It is that simple.

You can look from this perspective: Your client side code is just one way to communicate with Your server. Another way is using web browser + firebug. It is perfectly valid usage of Your server side application. And Your PHP code should not care how request reaches it.

So if Your current code does not allow You in Your PHP code feel comfortable and freely decide if is it update or topic creation than Your need to change Your server side code (and perhaps DB schema) as well.

Your current solution is not good, because if I know how to use firebug I would probably find out that "9d9b68ac2b1de18d3712096354b3c3a5" means "topic" and "3ac340832f29c11538fbe2d6f75e8bcc" means "update".

I think Your are trying to invent Your own [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) protection. So go on Internet and read about it.

Comment: these 2 hashes are not static... they change as inside there there is one random variable which contains 5 random characters(salt)... what if i add 1 more salt? - Another solution is simply go to function 1 to favorite Update and go to function 2 to favorite topic...

Comment: My bad I have missed that random salt str. But again -- it does not matter how data have reached Your server as long as it is valid and CSRF attack proof.

Comment: i did some research on CSRF and as i see it works on POST only... so by adding it it will cover me and i can use my method without any problems?